# How to get retrieve firebase list based on another observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm still quite confused with observables. They're very complicated.

I'm trying to write a service class that can be used to monitor the logged in user's addresses as an observable list. The problem is I guess the list reference itself changes when a user logs in or logs out.

```
export class AddressService {
  user: any;
  addresses$: FirebaseListObservable<Address[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private authService: AuthService) {
    authService.user$.subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = user;
      if (this.user) {
        this.addresses$ = this.db.list(`/users/${this.user.uid}/addresses`);
      } else {
        this.addresses$ = undefined;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

When I try to add a subscriber to the list I'm getting null, because I guess the `addresses$` is not defined when it's added because it depends on the logged in user first resolving.

```
// in a UI component
ngOnInit() {
  this.addresses = this.addressService.addresses$;
}
```

It's like I need a new observable that emits a new observable list when the user logs in! Was looking at http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/switch.html - perhaps this could work somehow?

**Edited update here**
This is what I came up with (just extracted from the class)

```
// users can monitor this to get the latest address book.
  addresses$: Observable<FirebaseListObservable<any>>;

  // keeps a reference to the address subject.
  private addressSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(Observable.empty());

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private authService: AuthService) {
    this.addresses$ = this.addressSubject.asObservable();
    authService.user$.subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = user;
      if (this.user) {
        this.addressSubject.next(this.db.list(`/users/${this.user.uid}/addresses`));
      } else {
        this.addressSubject.next(Observable.empty());
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want to do, in pseudocode, is this:

1. First call `authService` to retrieve the user id.
2. If the user exist, go and retrieve the addresses in database.
3. If not, simply return nothing.
4. Assign the result to `addresses$`, expose it as an observable.

If you break down the steps like this, then you won't find `Observables` confusing. As long as you know the method to do each task listed, you are good.

Here is the code:

```
export class AddressService {
    user: any;
    addresses$: FirebaseListObservable<Address[]>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private authService: AuthService) {
        //Step 4: assign the observable back to addresses$
        this.addresses$ =
            //Step 1: first call the auth service
            this.authService.user$.switchMap(user => {
                this.user = user;
                //Step 2: if user exist, call DB service
                if (this.user) {
                    return this.db.list(`/users/${this.user.uid}/addresses`);
                }
                //Step 3: else just return nothing
                else {
                    return Obsevable.empty()
                }
            })
    }
}
```

I have made some inline commments in the code, so that you can compare with the pseudocode.

Comment: ah I see, it kind of chains observables like promises, interesting. let me just check up what switchMap does in the docs. I got it working which I just posted in a question edit, but this is more succinct so I'll mark it correct, but probably just stick to my solution since it's working and I'm reluctant to change it...

Comment: `.switchMap()` is like `.then()` in the promise.

Comment: @RichardG ah, just saw your edit. Have a `Subject` works well too.

Comment: actually I changed it's better because it immediately returns the address list. had to make addresses$ an Observable<any> though otherwise it was giving me a compiler error I guess because of `Observable.empty()`